Postgres - difference in using higher and lower cardinality indexes, if I want same data set selected
I have a target table, and set of data that I need from this table can be retrieved using filtering on different columns, with different cardinality of values. All filter cases have indexes created, and I was thinking if there is a big (potential) performance difference in using one column as filter over another. Maybe with example it will be simple to explain:
Three tables - account (id, ...), product(account_id, id, ...) and sales(account_id, product_id, ...).
As some sort of admin user I want sale figures for two accounts, but the catch is - there is a bunch of other metrics involved, query become overburdened with business logic. And in the middle of the query I need a CTE with data from sales table, grouped by product_id. So, when joining sales I can join product table on product_id, OR, I can join on account_id. Just to be clear, sales data will be same in both cases, as sales for an account = sales for all products of the account. Joining on product_id will be using higher cardinality index of the sales table, joining on account_id will use lower cardinality index. My assumption is that any index needs to be traversed/searched, and longer index need more processor time (and memory?). So the question I have, is it worth worrying about higher vs lower (relative to each other) cardinality indexed columns for filtering?
Start of the query will be like:
WITH
  fancy_accounts_select AS (
    SELECT id AS account_id, ...
  ),
  product_with_all_the_stuff AS (
    SELECT id AS product_id, ...
  )

And I need to pick between:
  grouped_sales AS (
    SELECT s.product_id, other_metrics
    FROM sales s
    JOIN fancy_accounts_select a ON a.account_id = s.account_id
    GROUP BY s.product_id
  )

and
  grouped_sales AS (
    SELECT s.product_id, other_metrics
    FROM sales s
    JOIN product_with_all_the_stuff p ON p.product_id = s.product_id
    GROUP BY s.product_id
  )

Amount of data is what you would expect for such table names, but lets take ~1'000 accounts, ~10'000 products, ~100'000'000 sales. I am expecting query execution run time to be close, because Postgres is so darn fast nowadays, but wondering if there is something not so obvious that I've missed?

Postgres version 15

I couldn't find much about cardinality on Postgres index documentation page, EXPLAIN ANALYZE results are over the place, but lowest execution time I've seen for 'join on account_id' query is 0.5s, whereas for 'join on product_id' it was ~2s.

A verbal description is good, but where is the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output that would tell us the hard facts?

There are insufficient details from which to formulate recommendations. As @LaurenzAlbe mentioned, the output from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) would be helpful. You said, "Maybe with example it will be simple to explain," then didn't provide an actual example, but instead only presented query fragments. The DDL, including all indexes, explain plans, and full querie are all important. Please review [mre].

I don't really have a problem with both queries, I was thinking more about hypothetical situation where I should be focusing on making indexes on columns with lowest cardinality? Adding such columns where they are absent, creating composite indexes and similar stuff.
I could've rephrased myself this way: given account -> product -> sale relation, is it considered a good practice to have account_id in sale table, even though sale table never queried without product table, which already have account_id?

@Ilia Normally it is not a good idea to have redundant data in a database (copies of a value that are not used to implement a foreign key constraint). But in some cases you might do such a "denormalization" anyway because it may give you a necessary performance boost. You are not receiving a satisfactory answer because that cannot be determined in general, only for individual cases. If you don't have a use case for denormalization yet, don't do it.

Yes in such a case, all other things being equal, lower cardinality is better, because the index will be smaller.
This means it will be faster to load, don't use as much space in caches and faster to process.
The important parts of the answer are
"in such a case" and "all other things being equal".
A different case is when an index is used to filter the result, but it is not sufficient.
In such a case higher cardinality might be better, because it might be more restrictive.
Examples of not all things being equal:

Can part of the query satisfied by an index without accessing the respective table
columns in the index might be of different size
One index might be constantly in memory, because it is used by other parts of the application
...

So in the end, only benchmarks on your system under realistic load can give you a definitiv answer.

That were my general thoughts, except I didn't thought about index life outside of my query. I am sure lower cardinality index will have its uses later, so I will definitely consider adding column and index just in case. Thanks!
